QGIS copy and paste issues: unique constraints (id=5249) existed
In QGIS select features from one layer and copy them. Select the other layer with edit mode click "paste" tool. Then save the second layer, the error popups: the update can not be saved because of the unique   constrains rule problem , the "priValve_pkey"   DETAIL:  key "(id)=(5429)" existed.

Sounds like you are pasting a feature with an id that already exist in the second layer. Try deleting the id field in either table

My copy and paste procedure is wrong. I opened two QGIS applications. Copy from layer   A from one of the application and paste to Layer B of the second application. So this issue apeared. If the two layers are in one application , there will not this issue.
